# How to rename and join an elasticsearch server preserving data?

Tags: elasticsearch

I tested elasticsearch and decided to make a cluster. To this I renamed the node and defined a cluster

```
cluster.name = mycluster
node.name = firstnode
```

When restarting the changes are taken into account but the existing data is not visible anymore (`http://myserver.example.com:9200/_plugin/head/` show no indices).

When removing the two lines above and restarting the indices are back.

How can I rename the node preserving existing data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to rename the folder holding the data.

The folder created by default for a standalone server is called `elasticsearch`, renaming it to the cluster name (`mycluster` in the context of the question) makes the previous data available.